# How much stool and urine production per day should be considered normal at what age?

Tags: infant, newborn, age-appropriate

The baby (25 days old) produces wet/semi solid yellow stools once after 3 days. Is this considered constipation? Also, how many wet diapers (urination) should I expect from her per day on an average?

To keep this question generic please include age specific answers ***with references***.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to repeat the good work of others ... Baby Poop 101 has descriptions, pictures, and tons of info.

http://www.babycenter.com/0_baby-poop-a-complete-guide_10319333.bc

http://www.babycenter.com/404_how-many-times-a-day-does-a-breastfed-baby-normally-poop_8832.bc

My interpretation (and 20 year old recollection) of this ... your baby is a bit young to not be pooping with every feeding. Make sure you are feeding for long enough ... don't quit when he fusses .. burp and get back at it. Some mothers are not able to produce enough milk, so you may want to augment with some infant formula before bed and in the morning. It is basically impossible to overfeed at this age.

Along with this ... some advice. Don't over-think or over-analyze. Pay attention to your baby, but don't extrapolate every funny look or squirm into something serious.

Comment: Good references, but our daughter had a similar pattern to the OP's; at a month old, she might not poop at all one day, then have a massive blowout the next day. Pediatrician said it was normal; all her GI tract's peristalsis movements and other things we typically don't think too much about as adults just haven't quite gotten in gear at this age. The key is that the baby's having BMs on somewhat of a regular basis, meaning there's a clear path through the GI tract and no obstructions.

Answer (score 2):

It's perfectly normal for your baby to poop once in three to four days as most of the breast milk is easily digested and theres little left to dump out. The digestive system of babies develop only after birth, so don't get petrified by no poop for 3-4 days at a stretch. Ensure that after such a gap, the poop is profound though. The baby has to pee a minimum of six times per day though, which is a sign of good feeding and no dehydration.